# Squashing commits does not affect on original repository

Tags: git, github, squash

I'm trying to squash commits of a branch. Steps I followed:

- Cloned using `git clone -b <branch> <url>`
- Since I have 3 commits to squash used `git rebase -i HEAD~3`
- Changed `pick` to `squash` and saved.
- Finally gave status as success.

  `[detached HEAD b607ebc] <commit msg>
  Date: Mon Jul 10 23:01:25 2017 -0700
  5 files changed, 41 insertions(+), 5 deletions(-)
  Successfully rebased and updated refs/heads/<commit msg>.`

It did change the cloned project, but **didn't affect the original repository**.

I tried many options. But any of them didn't work. What am I doing wrong? Please help me with this. Thanks a lot.

Comment: you need to push force to change original repo

Comment: That worked. Thanks a lot. I tried push before. But only force push worked.

Comment: yes, because you changed history and you clone and original diverged

Comment: btw, if it's shared repo, other users can have problem when pulling. Probably they need to do hard reset.

Comment: Okay @Alexan thanks a lot for the tip